# Looking for iOS styled fastforward and rewind button images

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, avaudioplayer, uitabbar

I am building an app that will play music and in need of a little assistance. I understand how to implement everything programming wise, however, I have been unsuccessful finding fastforward and rewind images. These images will be used for UIButtons on a UIView. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this app out:

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

I think you'll find it invaluable.  Oh, and it also solves your current issue.

Comment: Awesome! I took a look at the link and it seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I will try it out shortly.